# Windows 10 RDP on VM is sometimes off

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, remote-desktop, sleep

I am getting some trouble with a Windows 10 on a virtual machine with a client connecting using RDP.
This week, everyday, not always the same moment of the day, the system is power off for no reason. I got multiple reasons from event logs.

The last one (this morning in France) is that the system was sleeping but I checked, all form of sleeping is disabled on this VM.

Do you know what could be the problem ?